# Getting type error while adding 2 dictionaries in KDB

Tags: kdb

I am able to add and assign the second dictionary `(s i)` to the one with `(d t)`

```
d1:`d`t!(.z.d ;.z.t)
d1,:`s`i!`VOD`L
d1
```

However the other way round does not work, I am getting type error :

```
d2:`s`i!`VOD`L
d2,:`d`t!(.z.d ;.z.t)
d2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, `(d t)` is making a heterogenous dictionary :

```
q)d1:`d`t!(.z.d ;.z.t)
q)type value d1
0h
```

now if you add and assign any homogeneous or heterogenous dictionary, it will work.

while in another case the first dictionary created is homogeneous , and it is throwing error when you add & assign a heterogenous dictionary (or homogeneous dictionary of another type for that matter )

```
q)d2:`s`i!`VOD`L
q)type value d2
11h
q)type value `d`t!(.z.d ;.z.t)
```

To solve this issue , you should only add the dictionary and then assign it.

```
q)d2:`s`i!`VOD`L
q)d2:d2, `d`t!(.z.d ;.z.t)
q)d2
s| `VOD
i| `L
d| 2018.03.25
t| 09:59:17.109
```

Answer (score 4):

When dictionary `d2` was created all of the values where symbols. When you try to update this using `d2,:` with non-symbol types it causes kdb to throw an error due to mismatched types. One way to prevent this is to add a null key to your dictionary that will ensure you can have mixed types for your values:

```
q)d2:enlist[`]!enlist(::)    / add null key
q)d2,:`s`i!`VOD`L
q)d2
 | ::
s| `VOD
i| `L
q)d2,:`d`t!(.z.d ;.z.t)
q)d2
 | ::
s| `VOD
i| `L
d| 2018.03.25
t| 09:42:52.754
```

If you investigate a namespace, for example `.q` or create your own, you will see that the null key exists, ensuring namespaces can contain mixed types.

Comment: `d2:1#.q` is equivalent to ```d2:enlist[`]!enlist(::)```. This can be found in q code and isn't very clear first time.